# Would you explain the usage and grammar of "shall"?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-shall

Would you please explain a little about the grammar of "shall"?

For example, in a book that I'm reading, there's this sentence:

> In the following, we ***shall*** consider the propagation of an electromagnetic wave in a linear medium (free of saturation and hysteresis), free of sources.

Why has "shall" been used here? What's the meaning of it? What's the usage of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used to indicate Future Tense, **shall** gives the statement the tone of *inevitability* and/or *natural progression*, in contrast to **will** which usually expresses the desire, the readiness to act by the subject.

In your example, the *consideration* ("*of the propagation of ...*") is the inevitable, although not necessarily immediate, outcome of moving forward with the text of the book.

The eager lover could ask of the object of his affection:

> Darling, **shall** I see you tonight?

, which inquires about the future that *doesn't* rely on *his own* decision, thus expressing the dependency on fate or circumstances.

If the same lover asks

> Darling, **will** I see you tonight?

, the answer could simply be, "I don't know, will you?", suggesting that the question itself contains the doubt or allusion to dependency on the **inquirer**'s knowledge and/or desire to meet.

---

The auxiliary verb **shall** is ubiquitous in legal documents.  By means of its use the language conveys the inevitability or the mandatory status of certain events or conditions:

> "Within 90 days after appointment, the special representative **shall** notify the heirs and legatees of the following information ..."
>   "A notary who accepts such instructions **shall** notify the heirs thereof and **shall** procure the registration..."